# Problems with kvno + Consultation with kerberos authentication settings

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, centos6, kerberos

I have clearly identified a problem that I can not solve.
I suspect I'm missing something when setting the service running on Centos 6 on Windows Server 2003.

First I tell the environment that I'm working and I'm trying to do, then the problem.

I have a Windows Server 2003 without SP1 whose IP is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and his name win2003srv2.ejemplo.org.

In this same team that Cyrus Imap Server I have also I have installed Thunderbird as mail client for testing.

In the Active Directory Windows Server 2003 add a new user called **imap** and has:

```
Logon Name: imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@ejemplo.org

Logon name of user (pre-Windows 2000): EJEMPLO\imap0.
```

Importantly @ejemplo.org not put in capitals because this set by default and can not be modified in the window to create the user.

I have added the SPN for imap, the list I have this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador>SETSPN -L prueba-mail
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=prueba-mail,CN=Computers,DC=ejemplo,DC=org:
    imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org:143
    imap/prueba-mail
    imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org
    host/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org
    host/prueba-mail
```

Also generate the keytab on Windows Server 2003:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\TEST>Ktpass -princ imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@EJEMPLO.ORG -mapuser imap -pass zzzzz -crypto DES-CBC-MD5 -out UNIXimap.keytab
Targeting domain controller: win2003srv2.ejemplo.org
Successfully mapped host/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org to imap0.
Key created.
Output keytab to UNIXimap.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 65 imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@EJEMPLO.ORG ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 4 etype 0x3 (DES-CBC-MD5) keylength 8 (0x85589d4fef0d5e20)
Account imap0 has been set for DES-only encryption.
```

Then add it to the keytab where I have imap server.

**PROBLEM:**

When I log with Thunderbird, I look at the wireshark (they are added at the end of this post) to request a TGS ticket "imap/test-mail.ejemplo.org" and not find it.

Also if I try to execute this command same thing happens:

```
kvno imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@EJEMPLO.ORG  
kvno: Server not found in Kerberos database while getting credentials for imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@EJEMPLO.ORG
```

However  kvno imap/test-mail@EJEMPLO.ORG works well:

```
kvno imap/prueba-mail@EJEMPLO.ORG
imap/prueba-mail@EJEMPLO.ORG: kvno = 59
```

That may be what this missing me to find the service?.

If you can find this "imap/prueba-mail@EJEMPLO.ORG" because I can locate an  "imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org@EJEMPLO.ORG"?.

I show below the contents of krb5.conf and catches I made with Wireshark, any help is appreciated.

------------------------- /etc/krb5.conf: ------------------------------------------------

```
[logging]
  default = /var/log/krb5libs.log
  kdc = /var/log/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = /var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
        rdns = false
        ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
        default_realm = EJEMPLO.ORG
        dns_lookup_kdc = false
        dns_lookup_realm = false

        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
        default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
        allow_weak_crypto = yes
        default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5
        default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5
[realms]
        FNR.GUB.UY = {
                kdc = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:88
        }

[domain_realm]
.fnr.gub.uy = EJEMPLO.ORG
[login]
        krb4_convert = false
```

------------------------------------- TGS-REQ ----------------------------------------------

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   6083 26.329448   yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx       KRB5     TGS-REQ

Frame 6083 (647 bytes on wire, 647 bytes captured)
    Arrival Time: Jul 26, 2013 11:24:05.747386000
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.012354000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 26.329448000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 26.329448000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 6083
    Frame Length: 647 bytes
    Capture Length: 647 bytes
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:kerberos]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: CadmusCo_13:dd:bd (08:00:27:13:dd:bd), Dst: Ibm_a5:b3:46 (00:09:6b:a5:b3:46)
    Destination: Ibm_a5:b3:46 (00:09:6b:a5:b3:46)
        Address: Ibm_a5:b3:46 (00:09:6b:a5:b3:46)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: CadmusCo_13:dd:bd (08:00:27:13:dd:bd)
        Address: CadmusCo_13:dd:bd (08:00:27:13:dd:bd)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol, Src: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy), Dst: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..0. = ECN-Capable Transport (ECT): 0
        .... ...0 = ECN-CE: 0
    Total Length: 633
    Identification: 0x43c1 (17345)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0.. = Reserved bit: Not Set
        .1. = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0 = More fragments: Not Set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (0x11)
    Header checksum: 0xa9c2 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad : False]
    Source: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy)
    Destination: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 58790 (58790), Dst Port: kerberos (88)
    Source port: 58790 (58790)
    Destination port: kerberos (88)
    Length: 613
    Checksum: 0x4d67 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Kerberos TGS-REQ
    Pvno: 5
    MSG Type: TGS-REQ (12)
    padata: PA-TGS-REQ
        Type: PA-TGS-REQ (1)
            Value: 6E8201C6308201C2A003020105A10302010EA20703050000... AP-REQ
                Pvno: 5
                MSG Type: AP-REQ (14)
                Padding: 0
                APOptions: 00000000
                    .0.. .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Use Session Key: Do NOT use the session key to encrypt the ticket
                    ..0. .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Mutual required: Mutual authentication is NOT required
                Ticket
                    Tkt-vno: 5
                    Realm: EJEMPLO.ORG
                    Server Name (Service and Instance): krbtgt/EJEMPLO.ORG
                        Name-type: Service and Instance (2)
                        Name: krbtgt
                        Name: EJEMPLO.ORG
                    enc-part rc4-hmac
                        Encryption type: rc4-hmac (23)
                        Kvno: 2
                        enc-part: 0ACDE6D2981DBF829935A102CB4A7700DD762C8CFFC4B183...
                Authenticator des-cbc-md5
                    Encryption type: des-cbc-md5 (3)
                    Authenticator data: 86588D7C6AA08BE142100084FBBB0968878E567AE10228B0...
    KDC_REQ_BODY
        Padding: 0
        KDCOptions: 50810000 (Forwardable, Proxiable, Renewable, Canonicalize)
            .1.. .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Forwardable: FORWARDABLE tickets are allowed/requested
            ..0. .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Forwarded: This is NOT a forwarded ticket
            ...1 .... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Proxiable: PROXIABLE tickets are allowed/requested
            .... 0... .... .... .... .... .... .... = Proxy: This ticket has NOT been proxied
            .... .0.. .... .... .... .... .... .... = Allow Postdate: We do NOT allow the ticket to be postdated
            .... ..0. .... .... .... .... .... .... = Postdated: This ticket is NOT postdated
            .... .... 1... .... .... .... .... .... = Renewable: This ticket is RENEWABLE
            .... .... ...0 .... .... .... .... .... = Opt HW Auth: False
            .... .... .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = Constrained Delegation: This is a normal request (no constrained delegation)
            .... .... .... ...1 .... .... .... .... = Canonicalize: This is a request for a CANONICALIZED ticket
            .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. .... = Disable Transited Check: Transited checking is NOT disabled
            .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 .... = Renewable OK: We do NOT accept renewed tickets
            .... .... .... .... .... .... .... 0... = Enc-Tkt-in-Skey: Do NOT encrypt the tkt inside the skey
            .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ..0. = Renew: This is NOT a request to renew a ticket
            .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ...0 = Validate: This is NOT a request to validate a postdated ticket
        Realm: EJEMPLO.ORG
        Server Name (Service and Host): imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org
            Name-type: Service and Host (3)
            Name: imap
            Name: prueba-mail.ejemplo.org
        till: 2013-07-27 00:14:39 (UTC)
        Nonce: 1374848677
        Encryption Types: des-cbc-md5
            Encryption type: des-cbc-md5 (3)
```

------------------------------------------ Reply -----------------------------------------

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   6084 26.330599   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx       yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy       KRB5     KRB Error: KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN

Frame 6084 (171 bytes on wire, 171 bytes captured)
    Arrival Time: Jul 26, 2013 11:24:05.748537000
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001151000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001151000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 26.330599000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 6084
    Frame Length: 171 bytes
    Capture Length: 171 bytes
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:kerberos]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Ethernet II, Src: Ibm_a5:b3:46 (00:09:6b:a5:b3:46), Dst: CadmusCo_13:dd:bd (08:00:27:13:dd:bd)
    Destination: CadmusCo_13:dd:bd (08:00:27:13:dd:bd)
        Address: CadmusCo_13:dd:bd (08:00:27:13:dd:bd)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: Ibm_a5:b3:46 (00:09:6b:a5:b3:46)
        Address: Ibm_a5:b3:46 (00:09:6b:a5:b3:46)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol, Src: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), Dst: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..0. = ECN-Capable Transport (ECT): 0
        .... ...0 = ECN-CE: 0
    Total Length: 157
    Identification: 0x1ed3 (7891)
    Flags: 0x00
        0.. = Reserved bit: Not Set
        .0. = Don't fragment: Not Set
        ..0 = More fragments: Not Set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: UDP (0x11)
    Header checksum: 0xd08c [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad : False]
    Source: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
    Destination: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: kerberos (88), Dst Port: 58790 (58790)
    Source port: kerberos (88)
    Destination port: 58790 (58790)
    Length: 137
    Checksum: 0xf316 [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Kerberos KRB-ERROR
    Pvno: 5
    MSG Type: KRB-ERROR (30)
    stime: 2013-07-26 14:24:37 (UTC)
    susec: 524733
    error_code: KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN (7)
    Realm: EJEMPLO.ORG
    Server Name (Service and Host): imap/prueba-mail.ejemplo.org
        Name-type: Service and Host (3)
        Name: imap
        Name: prueba-mail.ejemplo.org
    e-data
```